# vscode-remote-release and wsl 2

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Has anyone already tried `vscode-remote-release` with the pre release of wsl 2?

I am getting the following error when starting a new wsl server:

```
[2019-06-15 11:14:05.702] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL.
[2019-06-15 11:14:06.526] Launching C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe bash -c "./scripts/wslServer.sh 15b7c86d86319b187a5ef255c170184a8519c5af insider .vscode-server-insiders  " in c:\Users\User Name\.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.38.0
[2019-06-15 11:14:07.126] bash: ./scripts/wslServer.sh: No such file or directory
[2019-06-15 11:15:38.680] VS Code Server for WSL failed to start. No messages received for 90s
[2019-06-15 11:15:38.680] For help with startup problems, go to
[2019-06-15 11:15:38.680] https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
```

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue for SuperUser, or more likely the WSL GitHub issue tracker, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

It seems wsl2 entry path problem, try execute wsl in any folder. If your shell enter your linux's user home and not the /mnt/ path to your windows's folder path.

Currently I found reboot can resolve this problem for a while

Comment: I had similar problem as detailed here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/21#issuecomment-506377449. Bash was starting in the wrong path. Rebooting solved the problem.